# Windows.Resource for Overriding the Mouse Over Event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have seen a few questions close to mine, maybe I am just having a hard time understanding. I started using WPF about a week ago. My program adds buttons dynamically based off of a set of files. Everything is working great except for that I am having a hard time with getting rid of the default mouse over event for the buttons. I give the buttons image backgrounds as I create them, but the mouse over event makes the buttons a blueish grey. Below is some code that I have started, maybe I am on the right track?

Thanks

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <Button x:Key="MoviePosterStyle">
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">                   
                </Trigger>                    
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a local copy of the buttons template in a style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
          <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
          </Trigger>
          <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBEE6FD"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
        </Trigger>-->
          <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFC4E5F6"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF2C628B"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBCDDEE"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF245A83"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="#FF838383"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

and then remove or outcomment the IsMouseOver Trigger as shown above.